# Infinite Loop Banner

Tags: php, javascript, image, infinite-loop, banner

Excuse me. I am beginner for this code web :)

I have 3 images for my banner...
I dont want appear image banner same as `random()` statement
I have tried an array multidimensional php

`$images[0] = ("1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg");`
`$images[1] = ("2.jpg","3.jpg","1.jpg");`
`$images[2] = ("3.jpg","1.jpg","2.jpg");`

I want to change the position every refresh of my image like `$images(array)` above 
My code like this :

`<?php`
`$a=1;`
`$i=3;`
`while($a<=$i){`
`$images[$a] = ("$appear");}`
`//$appear is list of image above but I create it with random()`
`?>`

I have 2 question for this problem :

1. I want to get value where `$a=1` and `$a=2` images appear as 
   `$images[1] = ("2.jpg","3.jpg","1.jpg");`and
   `$images[2] = ("3.jpg","1.jpg","2.jpg");`
   Could I get that value?
    which code would I use?
2. I want to use javascript for recall `$a=1;` 
   if `$a` had finished (for loop again)....
   Could you help me?

---

I am sorry if My Attitude and My Language is fall apart
I hope you can understand My Idea 
Thank you for you greatful ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you thinking about this.....
for refreshing you have to use session variables

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_session['a']))
         $_session['a'] = 1;
    $a = $_session['a']; // retrieves the value even you refreshes the page
    $i=3;
    while(1){
        $images[$a] = ("$appear");
        $a = $a + 1; 
        if($a>3)
            $a=1;
        $_session['a'] = $a; //stores the value even you refreshes the page
    }

?>
```

it will reset the $a value to 1 when it reaches 3
If is this you are looking for..?

Comment: Thank you for your answer...^^ <br/> I want it changes every the browser is refresh. No problem for the `random()`

Comment: then use the value as the session variable
$_sesion['a']

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have some syntax issues.

Arrays in PHP are in this form: 
    $images = array('1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg');

if you want a random image use:
    $image = array_rand($images);

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your answer ^^. But I want a different image appear not same image like `$images[$a]=("1.jpg","2.jpg","1.jpg")`